# Writing C++ code for Linux platform in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am writing code in VS that should be ported later to Linux. I found that sometimes, I may use some functions or code that is available only on Windows and not on Linux.

Is there any way that I can set my Visual Studio to report me these non portable pieces of code?

I prefer to use VS during development and then use the code base and compile it in Linux.

Comment: You can set up a configuration that uses e.g. [MinGW and MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/) or something similar, and use the GNU compiler and have it set up to build as if it was in a Linux environment.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. That is a solution but I like to use MSVC natively but MSVC just stop me from compiling codes which are windows specific.

Comment: Disable the windows only compiler extensions and don't use any windows libraries and you should be more or less fine. This means you shouldn't include windows.h for instance and use a third party library (such as QT) for your GUI. Also, you could use cmake together with VS and with little or no changes compile the same project on a linux system.

Comment: The tricky bit is of course Boost, which will happily use Windows-specific code and still compile on Linux (because it also has Linux-specific code).

Comment: Set up a Linux CI server so you can keep an eye on the build. That way you'll know when you've done something that only works in MSVC or g++

Answer (score 0):

You can treat MinGW as a reference compiler, just to check whether the code you write is portable.

You can also disable MSVC compiler extensions in the compiler options settings in Project Properties (or set `/Za` flag). That will most likely make at least `<windows.h>` stop compiling.

Frankly, though, I don't see a problem in simply not using nonportable things. Stick to standard library and libraries that you know are portable and you're good to go. (granted, syntactic extensions are easier to accidentally use, but then again their usages are also typically trivial to put back in proper way).